# Check if a number is in a range

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I need to check to see if a number is in a given range inclusively, the code I have works except for when all three numbers are the same. I should get a 1 but get a 0 instead. And I can only use the following operations `! ~ & ^ | + << >>`.

```
int isInRange(int x, int lbound, int ubound) {
   int first = ubound + (~x);
   int first1 = ~(first +1);
   int hold = x + (~lbound);
   int hold1 = ~(hold +1);
   int final = (first1 +hold1);
   int final1 = final >> 31;
   int final2 = final1 & 1;
   int final3 = !final2;
   return final3;
```

Comment: what is wrong with `return x >= lbound && x <= ubound;`?

Comment: Forgot to mention: can only use bitwise operators ! ~ & ^ | + << >>.

Comment: I checked out the link, it leaves me with the same problem

Comment: No it doesn't, I give the answer there. All you have to do is rewrite the subtractions in my answer to match your list of allowed operators.

Comment: By the way, you're making (in addition to other mistakes) the same mistake that *everyone* is making: if `a - b` is negative, that does *not* imply that `a < b`, and if `a - b` is positive, that does *not* imply that `a >= b`. Rewriting your subtractions to additions and complements does not change that.

Comment: @harold I dont understand your solution; what do x and y represent in your solution?

Comment: It depends. The line with the `x` and `y` in it is just for the predicate `x < y`. You need two of those, once with `x = x, y = lbound`, and once with `x = ubound, y = x` (I realize it's confusing now because of the two different meanings of `x`, but that's how it is)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/48989/discussion-between-user3316874-and-harold)